# What is "er's" construction?

Tags: pronoun

For example

> Wenn jemanden etwas stört, sagt er's offen und direkt

How is this different

> Wenn jemanden etwas stört, sagt er offen und direkt

Comment: I'm not sure whether the second sentence is intentionally written as it is. As it stands, it sounds incomplete - "sagt er" ... ja, was sagt er denn? This part should be extended to "sagt er es". But then, this is kind of directly a part of the answer, so I'm not sure whether the omission is intentional or not.

Comment: The last sentence is incorrect. It should be 'sagt er es' in the last sentence. And the first sentence is just a colloquial contraction.

Answer (score 4):

The verb *sagen* is transitive in German, just as "to say" is transitive (for most meanings) in English. In other words you have to mention what is said, even if it's only with a pronoun. So in English, you'd have to include the "it" in "If something bothers someone, they say it openly and directly." Similarly, German allows you to contract the *es* to *'s*, but as noted in the comments, dropping it entirely sounds wrong, even if the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 3):

In "**er's**", the apostrophe marks the omission of letters, it replaces "**... er es**".

A similar use of the apostrophe exists in English, e.g. "**it is**" -> "**it's**" or "**do not**" -> "**don't**".

On Wikipedia you can find an [explanation of the uses of the apostrophe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostroph) in the German language (in German).